# Matching subtree recursively in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, match, subtree, nosql

I'm using Neo4j, and I consider myself quite a newbie, and I don't really understand how I can select a subtree of my graph. I've found solutions using the `shortestPath` and `allShortestPaths` but that's not really the same thing as selecting a whole subtree by variable and all its children.

What I want to do is e.g. match `MATCH (n {name: "Sovrum"})-[r:CHILDOF]->(child) return n, child` but that only gives me the directly related nodes. [image]

Instead I want to select the whole subtree. 
[image]

Is there any good way of doing this or am I missing some vital point in how stuff works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy with variable length paths, you start at the root and tell Cypher to match CHILD_OF all the way down until it doesn't go further.

Please make sure to use labels in your query to allow Neo4j (with an index) to find your starting point quickly.

You can also assign the pattern matched to a path and return that path

```
MATCH path = (n:Node {name: "Sovrum"})-[:CHILDOF*]->(child)
RETURN path
```

Comment: Allright, this works. But I don't quite understand what the asterisk does with the relation?

Comment: The asteriks denotes a variable length path, see: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/introduction-pattern.html#_variable_length